# Is there a better way to iterate through pointer without reassigning it to a different variable?

Tags: c

```
struct hello1 {
    int64_t world1;
    int64_t world2;
    int64_t world3;
    int64_t world4;
    int64_t world5;
}

void something (struct hello1 *first) {

    int64_t *foo1 = &first->world1;

    for (int64_t i = 0; i < 0x30; i++) {
        printf("Address: 0xllx", foo1);
        foo1++;
    }
}
```

I'm currently assigning the address, `&first->wordl1`, to *foo1.

Is there a better way to increment to the next pointer within the struct without creating `int64_t *foo1`?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you expect it to look like, can you show us (even if your expectation doesn't actually work)?

Comment: The correct way to print an address (really a `void *`) is `%p`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*. Not to mention that the structure only have five members, but you try to iterate over *48* values.

Comment: And what is your *actual* problem? Why do you need to iterate over pointers to member variables in a structure? Why can't you use an array instead? AT the moment, this is too much of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No `%` is used here and therefore no *undefined behavoir* **for type mismatch** will invoked in this case.

Comment: Carol, Why does code attempt to iterate to 0x30?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [how not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before posting a question. We need to understand the problem correctly *and* entirely so please add all the necessary details that clarify your issue and/or (when related to code) post a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MCRE) with the actual and expected behavior as well as (if possible) the actual input.

Comment: Are you not allowed to use arrays?

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour on attempting to reach any member of the `struct` from any other member via pointer arithmetic is *undefined*.

In more detail, the C standard allows you to read the pointer value `&world1` (and dereference it), and the pointer value `&world1 + 1` (but *not* deferencing it). But it does not allow you to read the pointer value `&world1 + 2` and above.

Consider using an array of `int64_t` instead. Then pointer arithmetic will be valid, and you won't need those extra casts.

If you're stuck with `hello1` as it is and want to be able to access a member by an index then consider

```
inline int64_t* getHello1Element(struct hello1* h, size_t i)
{
    switch (i){
    case 0:
        return &h->world1;
    case 1:
        return &h->world2;
    case 2:
        return &h->world3;
    case 3:
        return &h->world4;
    case 4:
        return &h->world5;
    }
}
```

which will be O(1) with a good compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `i` to `&first->world1` directly.

```
struct hello1 {
    int64_t world1;
    int64_t world2;
    int64_t world3;
    int64_t world4;
    int64_t world5;
}

void something (struct hello1 *first) {

    for (int64_t i = 0; i < 0x30; i++) {
        printf("Address: 0xllx", &first->world1 + i);
    }
}
```

Note that this will invoke *undefined behavior* because it will make the resulting pointer out-of-range.

Also note that `printf()` itself won't result in *undefined behavior*: there are not `%` in the format and having extra arguments in `printf()` is allowed. (the extra arguments will be evaluated and ignored)

`&first->world1 + i` will cause nothing in typical environment, so let's remove this useless undefined behavior.
Also `0x30` will fit `int` (guaranteed to be able to store upto `32767`), so let's use simply `int` instead of `int64_t` for `i`.
Here is a better way:

```
struct hello1 {
    int64_t world1;
    int64_t world2;
    int64_t world3;
    int64_t world4;
    int64_t world5;
}

void something (struct hello1 *first) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 0x30; i++) {
        printf("Address: 0xllx");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is UB for any value of `i` other than 0 or 1. Lots of pitfalls in C!

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I don't know. OP used that and I inherited that. Note that this is NOT a format specifier including `%`.

Comment: Ah yes `%` missing.

Comment: How should your "better" way should work either? How are the `worldN`s guarenteed to be allocated in adjacent memory inside of the structure? And how does `printf("Address: 0xllx");` work to print the addresses of each `worldN` member of the structure?

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic way:

```
struct hello1 {
    int64_t world[5];
}

void something (struct hello1 *first) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Address: %p\n", first->world + i);
    }
}
void something_else(struct hello1 *first) {
    int64_t *foo = first->world;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Address: %p\n", foo++);
    }
}
```

or if you want to get playful:

```
struct hello1 {
    union {
       int64_t world[1];
       int64_t world1;
    };
    int64_t world2, world3, world4, world5;
}
```

But it is of more dubious value unless you have to jam in a separate accessor to support a lump of legacy.

Comment: What's the point of the second example? Shouldn't one have a decent memory waste there because for the union is allocated space for 5 `int`s and beside you allocating 4 other `int`s too? - And how does that allow adjacent memory that you can iterate with safety?

Comment: I am getting so sloppy, thanks...

Comment: You should cast addresses to print via `%p` to `void*`.